# Need to pass the current tab name to the backing managed bean from dynamically generated tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, tabview

I am using primefaces. And my requirement is to have number of tabs which will be generated based on a list specified in the backing bean. Now the second criteria is that if the tab changes the content under that tab should also changes. So I kept the onChange event and tried to get the value through event.getTab().getTitle(), but it is returning null to the backing bean.

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" binding="#{dndProductsView.tabView}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{dndProductsView.onTabChange}"/>
</p:tabView>
```

Managed Bean required codes are as :-

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    user = SessionBean.getUserName();
    categorylist = categoryLogics.findAllOrderedByCategoryName();
    productList = productLogics.findAllOrderedByProductName();
    droppedProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
}

private TabView tabView;

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
    this.tabView = tabView;
}

public TabView getTabView() {
    tabView = new TabView();
    for (Category c : categorylist) {
        Tab t = new Tab();
        t.setTitle(c.getCategoryName());
        tabView.getChildren().add(t);
    }
    return tabView;
}

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    String titleName =  event.getTab().getTitle();
    System.out.println("" + titleName);
}
```

The tab is getting generated properly and when the tab changes, the onTabChange() method is called but event.getTab().getTitle() returns null.

Comment: Ofcourse, I am not going to print the tab title. I just want that value so that I can run a search in the database based on that title value to fetch the products associated with that category.

Comment: Using `binding` on a bean property and manipulating the component tree in a bean method is always fishy, definitely if bean is in a broader scope than the request scope. Try avoiding that to all extent and simply do the job in XHTML instead. Replace it by `<p:tabView value="#{dndProductsView.categorylist}" var="category">` conform showcase example and retry.

Comment: I had tried that before and the same error was coming. Can you just guide me to any other way where I can generate categories and the event on the categories can send something( useful) to the backend beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Integer index=(Integer)tabview.getActiveIndex();
```

It is not a name but it is index of activ tab witch in this case is the one you are interested in.
Index starts from 0 being the first tab :)

Comment: While you are right the index can be used, it is a different approach. OP did not try to get something like `getActiveTitle()`, since then you were 100% right. OP tried to get the tab from the event (which works) but the title is empty. So while your anwer is good (and maybe even a better approach), the `getTitle()` being null does not seem ok imo

Comment: Well he is creating tabs dynamically and setting title from some action that can go wrong, so his title can end up empty, while active tab is always active tab if it exists, if not there is no onTabChange in a first place. And it will in some way solve the problem of empty title :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is the tab view is going to have the  value from a list in the backing bean which itself going to get the value from the database and of course that's totally dynamic. So even if I get the index value I won't be able to attach it the specific list details to which it belongs.

Comment: So you are saying that if you have index of element in the list you can't get   categorylist.get(index)? and return directly element that has created the same tabs by going thru that same list? Why?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. I earlier thought that the indexing of the tabs and the backend bean list had different indexing.